# Input Conditioning Op-Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

I found this circuit for conditioning the signal for the PedalShield Uno(Guitar Effect Pedal made using Arduino). I am trying to make a similar project and I copied the circuit but the Op-Amp that I have bought (only one available) is AD8051. The one on the circuit is supposed to be TL972.

I have no understanding of these matters and I would very much appreciate if you can point out the different parts of this circuit and its functionalities. I only know the first part before the op-amp are low-pass filters. I would like to understand this circuit so I can make my own for the AD8051 or if I can avail the TL061.[image]

Comment: Have you compared the datasheets?

Comment: I tried but I don't understand a single thing. We are taught only on the software area.

Comment: Will it work? What is the functionality of a "PedalShield Uno". Don't assume everyone will know this especially the guys who are more senior AND, those guys are the ones more likely to give better detailed answers on op-amps.

Comment: @Andyaka cheeky young whipper-snapper, I'll come around there and box your ears if I can remember where my zimmer frame is. By the way, what's an UNO? Used to be league of nations in my day (lol)

Comment: Sorry for not indicating what it is. Edited my question.

UNO is a version of Arduino boards.

Comment: This is not about electronic design since you have no interest in understanding the circuit, and only want to know *"Can I plug dis inta dat?*". We are not here for that. Also, no links to the datasheets.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have the background knowledge for these stuff. If you can point me out on what theories or articles to read or search for that would be awesome :D
Also, no links cause my reputation doesn't allow it yet. I'm new here and I'm very sorry for my mistakes and thanks for pointing them out. Helps in making my future questions better. :)

Comment: "We are taught only on the software area" is a weak excuse when you try to **design** something. If you need to use something you can't fully understand, simply pay for it.

Comment: @warren This might help in your research http://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=replace+op+amp

Comment: @WarrenGojar There are several specs that you need to meet or exceed when switching opamps. These include bandwidth, the voltage range, current output and slew rate. For audio amps you are also concerned with distortion and noise. It would probably be best if you learned about op-amps and then learned about the properties of op-amps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AD8051 is a rail to rail low input current (2uA) Op Amp but uses 10x input bias current than the TL972 and even higher offset current,  so is not well suited to this amplifier  with  unbalanced resistances   1M on (+) and 100K on (-).

This would result in a pop when plugged in from DC offset.

Also the pin numbers are different.

Try to get the right part or use a fine tune range for 2,5V ref if using a 5V supply or V+/2 if not to null the offset , then AC couple the output..

Answer (score 1):

Tony Stewart's answer is correct, but I'll add this. The AD8051 is 100 times faster than the TL972. As a result, since you don't know anything about building this stuff, I'll pretty much guarantee that if you try this it will oscillate at very high (MHz) frequency, get hot, and the audio output will sound crappy.